# Как сгруппировать элементы исходного списка в другой список со списками с заранее заданным количеством элементов?

Tags: python

У меня есть список `[элемент_1, элемент_2, .... элемент_N]`.

Как получить из исходного списка список, состоящий из нескольких списков, содержащих элементы исходного списка с заранее заданным количеством элементов?

Т.е. `[элемент_1, элемент_2, .... элемент_N] -> [[элемент_1, элемент_2, .... элемент_K], [элемент_K+1, элемент_K+2, .... элемент_M], [элемент_M+1, элемент_M+2, элемент_N],]`.

Например, если есть исходный список с 86 элементами, надо что бы получился список с, например, 4 списками по 20 элементов и одного списка с 6 элементами (остаток).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться простым `list comprehension` и индексированием:

```
In [55]: lst = list(range(1, 87))

In [56]: K = 20

In [57]: res = [lst[i:i+K] for i in range(0, len(lst), K)]

In [58]: print(res)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 3
7, 38, 39, 40], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 7
1, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86]]
```

Длины "суб-списков":

```
In [60]: [len(x) for x in res]
Out[60]: [20, 20, 20, 20, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [36]: from funcy import partition, chunks # pip install funcy

In [37]: array = list(range(87))

In [38]: len(list(partition(20, array))) # Без остатков
Out[38]: 4

In [39]: result = list(chunks(20, array)) # С остатками

In [40]: result[-1]
Out[40]: [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86]
```

Подробнее о том [что такое `funcy` читайте тут.](https://github.com/Suor/funcy)

Или можем реализовать по своему:

```
In [68]: def foo(array, count):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     for i in range(count, len(array), count):
    ...:         result.append(array[len(sum(result, [])):i])
    ...:     if len(sum(result, [])) != len(array):
    ...:         result.append(array[len(sum(result, [])):])
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [69]: result = foo(array, 20)

In [70]: len(result)
Out[70]: 5

In [71]: result[-1]
Out[71]: [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86]
```